# language support in a custom urdu theme

Tags: theme-development, language

I am planning to start work on an urdu (language in pakistan) website theme. basically, it will be a newspaper themed website. Can anyone tell me how can i add urdu support in my theme. I dont want to change Admin UI language. Just whatever posts/pages I will insert should be in my native language.
Any positive ideas will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Language files? Take a look at translational functions (i18n) in Codex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [files for the default Urdu theme](http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/ur/) to see what is necessary.

[WP Polyglots](http://wppolyglots.wordpress.com/?s=urdu) has some information too, the most important changes for 3.4 are listed on a [dedicated page](http://wppolyglots.wordpress.com/important-changes-for-wordpress-3-4/).

I think the main point are the fonts: Don’t rely on the browsers capability to find the best font file, embed a [Urdu font](https://www.google.com/search?q=free%20urdu%20font) per `@font-face{}` instead.